# Where to find memory addresses of a process in _EPROCESS

Tags: windows, memory-management

I am working on some memory forensics for fun and training. I try to find the (virtual) addresses in memory used by the process. At runtime, this is not that difficult (I use vmmap), but I try to understand, where these information are stored by the process. I am able to find the _EPROCESS or PET of the process in memory dump, but I have no idea, where the process stores its addresses. Where is this information stored in Windows OS? Especially, when the process needs more than a 4K page..,

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not played with it myself but, in theory, the translation from virtual to physical address is performed using a structure called the PDT table. When a process is running, a pointer to this table is always stored in the register CR3. This pointer indicates a physical memory address (otherwise it would be impossible to resolve the base address of the PDT).

When there is a context switch and another process starts running, the value of CR3 is updated with the physical address of the PDT for the new process, which is stored in the `_KPROCESS` (`Pcb` field of the `_EPROCESS`) of the new process, in field `DirectoryTableBase`. Once you have the base address of the PDT, you can perform the translation from virtual to physical address.

A more in-depth explanation of this, with WinDbg examples, can be found in https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/translating-virtual-to-physical-address-on-windows-physical-addresses/